# How to run a custom command when run the 'rails server' command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line, automation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the DelayedJob gem. In order to automate processes in *development* mode I would like to "auto"-run the following command

```
rake jobs:work
```

when in my console\terminal I run this other command

```
rails server

# and/or
#
# rails db:create
# rails db:migrate
# ...
```

**Is it possible? How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2):

The gem "foreman" will sort this out for you. Here's the railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman